# jQuery closes side-menu as soon as it opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a side-menu using the [Gentallela](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index2.html) theme as my basis, however, when I click a menu item it immediately opens and then closes itself.  The desired result is for it to stay open.

Right now my code is pretty simple and an exact copy of the theme itself.  It seemed to work initially, since the `li` element gets the `active` class, but for some reason the `active` class is revoked and the menu collapses. What is wrong here?

**sidenav.html.erb**

```html
<!-- menu links -->
      <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">

        <div class="menu_section">
          <h3>General</h3>
          <ul class="nav side-menu">
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                <li><a href="general_elements.html">General Elements</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Data Presentation <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                <li><a href="chartjs.html">Chart JS</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**custom.js**

```js
var URL = window.location,
    $BODY = $('body'),
    $MENU_TOGGLE = $('#menu_toggle'),
    $SIDEBAR_MENU = $('#sidebar-menu'),
    $SIDEBAR_FOOTER = $('.sidebar-footer'),
    $LEFT_COL = $('.left_col'),
    $RIGHT_COL = $('.right_col'),
    $NAV_MENU = $('.nav_menu'),
    $FOOTER = $('footer');

$(function () {
         
    $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a').on('click', function(ev) {
        var $li = $(this).parent();

        if ($li.hasClass('.active')) {
          $li.removeClass('active');
          $('ul:first', $li).slideUp(function(){
              setContentHeight();
          });
        } else {
          $li.addClass('active');
          $('ul:first', $li).slideDown(function(){
              setContentHeight();
          });

        }
      
});
```

With some drastic edits to the initial JQuery (posted above) I now have a menu opening, but when another is selected, it's not closing the others.  Instead, any element clicked is getting to keep the `active` class.

Comment: include jquery in your head section

Comment: @SaiKiranUppu I am... `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: May be you should debug the JS code with browser developer tool bar to see the code execution flow. I think the `If` block is being executed in the place of `else`

Comment: Have you tried alternatives like `.hasClass()` instead of `.is()`. Also, `console.log` in each step or breakpoint of the code, so after every `if` or `else` add a `console.log` so you can have a better idea of how the code is stepping through the functions, should make it easier to debug and troubleshoot.

Comment: Just updated the code to add console.log output... @UncaughtTypeError ... I'm going to try changing the `.is` to `.hasClass` and see what happens.

Comment: `if (!$li.parent().is('.child_menu'))`: why negate your if clause?

Comment: @Huelfe I don't think it's negating it since it's asking if the clicked elements parent is `.child_menu`, which it may be, which is for the submenu elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a complete refactor, the below works.  I'm not really a JS guy, so I'm sure it's flawed somewhere...:

**custom.js**

```
$SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a').on('click', function(ev) {
    var $li = $(this).parent();

    if ($li.hasClass('.active')) {
      $li.removeClass('active');
      $('ul:first', $li).slideUp(function(){
          setContentHeight();
      });
    } else {
      $li.addClass('active');
      $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('.side-menu li').not($li).removeClass('active');
      $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('.side-menu li').not($li).find('.child_menu').removeClass('active').slideUp();
      $('ul:first', $li).slideDown(function(){
          setContentHeight();
      });
    }
```